# how to launch a launch file from python code

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am working on voice and i want to launch a file from within my python script what i have tried is

```
if command == 'that':
        file_path =  "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_tutorials/launch/controller_spawner.launch"
        execfile(file_path)

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1346657638.343076] bad callback: <bound method TalkBack.talkback of <__main__.TalkBack instance at 0x9bcca8c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/pi_speech_tutorial/nodes/talkback.py", line 79, in talkback
    execfile(file_path)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_tutorials/launch/controller_spawner.launch", line 1
    <!-- -*- mode: XML -*- -->
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use `execfile` because it runs a python file. Launch files are xml files that describe which parameters to set and which nodes to run.

To execute a launch file, you can use `subprocess.call` to execute roslaunch and give it either the absolute path to your launch file or two parameters where the first is the package of your launch file and the second is the name of the file.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) on 2015-07-13**:
Given that roslaunch is implemented in python, this answer seems a little dissatisfying.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the following line

```
...
os.system("roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch")
...
```

to be able to use os.system, you need to import corresponding package

```
import os
```

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-12-07**:
This blocks the program when the os.system("xxx") ran.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something like this would work

```
  import roslaunch

  uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
  roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
  launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid, [file_path])
  launch.start()
```

---

Originally posted by [afakih](https://answers.ros.org/users/24990/afakih/) with karma: 206 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2016-05-20**:
@afakih this works. But I am trying to workout how you can launch along with arguments?

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-11-23**:
@naveedhd have you found out any solution to this yet?

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-12-07**:
`launch.shutdown()  #stops the ROSLaunchParen object.` That's really cool~

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-19**:
arguments are supported as of `lunar`: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage#Roslaunch_file_with_command_line-style_arguments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-07-07**:
I don't intend to denounce this answer, but just want to raise an attention that as of July 2018 `roslaunch` API is declared as [unstable](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/#Stability.2BAC8-Roadmap).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the following frequently, for instance in ros tests.

```
import roslaunch
package = 'package_name'
executable = 'node.py'
node_name = 'nodename'
node = roslaunch.core.Node(package=package, node_type=executable, name=node_name, output='screen')
launch = roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch()
launch.start()
process = launch.launch(node)
```

The only problem I still couldn't solve is, how to launch nodes outside of the main thread.

[EDIT]

I have now also solved the problem about launching nodes outside the main thread within callbacks. The following code snippet illustrates the solution. It also shows, how you can start nodes with launch file programmatically. However, instructing the command line programmatically is not nice but the only way I was able to make it work.

```
import rospy
import os
import rospy
import rospkg
import subprocess
import roslaunch
from std_srvs.srv import Trigger, TriggerResponse
    
def start_node_direct():
    """
    Does work as well from service/topic callbacks directly using rosrun
    """    
    package = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
    node_name = 'YOUR_NODE.py'

    command = "rosrun {0} {1}".format(package, node_name)

    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

    state = p.poll()
    if state is None:
        rospy.loginfo("process is running fine")
    elif state < 0:
        rospy.loginfo("Process terminated with error")
    elif state > 0:
        rospy.loginfo("Process terminated without error")


def start_node2():
    """
    Does work as well from service/topic callbacks using launch files
    """    
    package = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
    launch_file = 'YOUR_LAUNCHFILE.launch'

    command = "roslaunch  {0} {1}".format(package, launch_file)

    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

    state = p.poll()
    if state is None:
        rospy.loginfo("process is running fine")
    elif state < 0:
        rospy.loginfo("Process terminated with error")
    elif state > 0:
        rospy.loginfo("Process terminated without error")

def start_node():
    """
    Does not work if called from service/topic callbacks due to main signaling issue
    """
    package = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
    launch_file = 'YOUR_LAUNCHFILE.launch'
    uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
    roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
    launch_file = os.path.join(rospkg.RosPack().get_path(package), 'launch', launch_file)
    launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid, [launch_file])
    launch.start()

def service_callback(req):

    # edit below for other options
    #start_node()
    #start_node2()
    start_node_direct()

    return TriggerResponse(success=True)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('test1', anonymous=True)
    
    service = rospy.Service('launch', Trigger, service_callback)
    
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) with karma: 46 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
Do you have a particular reason for not using the `rostest` infrastructure for this?

**Comment by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) on 2018-03-29**:
@gvdhoorn yes I am often starting/debugging my tests directly from pycharm and not requiring any launch-file-based setup simplifies this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2 you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a `LaunchDescription` object. If you have seen a regular python launch file, this is what `generate_launch_description()` returns. This object contains information about nodes to be launched, etc.
2. Create a `LaunchService` object from `launch` python module.
3. Pass the `LaunchDescription` to `LaunchService` using `include_launch_description` method of the `LaunchService` instance.
4. Use `run` method of the `LaunchService`. (Use more advanced functions if you need async, etc. See more info [here.](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst))

Here's an example:

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command
import launch_ros


def generate_launch_description():
    model_path = '/path/to/my/robot.urdf'

    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', model_path])}]
    )

    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros', 
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-entity', 'sam_bot', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen'),
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        spawn_entity,
    ])


def main():
    launch_description = generate_launch_description()
    launch_service = launch.LaunchService()
    launch_service.include_launch_description(launch_description)
    launch_service.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [m2-farzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/73017/m2-farzan/) with karma: 56 on 2021-06-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2